# says/is saying - which to use here?

Tags: verbs

I don't get what he **says** most of the time.

I don't get what he **is saying** most of the time.

Do both the sentences mean the same thing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use present simple to talk about something that is generally true, for example, something that is true every time that he speaks. Note that, with **says**, this can also relate to an opinion that the subject always holds,  although this meaning is probably not applicable in this context. An example where this meaning applies would be:

> He says that he is innocent - *an opinion the speaker always holds*

We use present continuous to talk about what's happening right now: with **is saying**, it relates only to the words coming out of his mouth, not to any opinion that he holds.

When you append **most of the time**, this indicates that you ware talking about a probability that something is true.

The first of your sentences sounds confusing because the present simple indicates that something is generally true, however "most of the time" indicates a probability.

The second is clearer because you are describing the probability that you would understand the words coming out of his mouth on any particular occasion.

> I don't understand what he says - *generally true*
>   I don't understand what he says most of the time - *confusing: generally true or probability?*
>   I don't understand what he is saying most of the time - *probability*

Note that the use of the word **get** rather than **understand** is informal, and in informal speech the normal conventions are somewhat relaxed, so you may hear the first sentence even though it is potentially confusing.

Comment: But most of the time is closer to habit(present simple), a recurrent thing,  a general fact than a probability.